# Audit log plugin - Log deleted object?

Tags: grails, audit-logging

Great plugin, really helpful.

http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging

However, I have a question on Delete events being logged, so currently if an object is deleted (hard delete) is there a way to track some of the attributes of the deleted object cause i hate the whole ideology of soft delete when i can actually log everything.

Or may be there is a way i can log the deleted object?

I tried using it, audit log says particular object was deleted, however we have no way to have that object.